# Array of Images Ruby to check what each value starts with

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have an array of different images. I am trying to confirm that if the images start with the right name.

```
images = ["nginx", "help-me-1"]

images.each_with_index {|image, i| images[i].start_with?('help-me')}
```

Unfortunately its not looping through correctly, and I'm unsure whats wrong. I don't get an error message of any sort, and I've added some logging expecting some and do not. What might I be missing?

Comment: What do you want to happen when you come across an image that starts with the string you give? At the moment your code goes through each object in 'images' and returns true if it starts with the string

Comment: That's array of strings, not images.

Comment: It's also much nicer to write: images.each { |image| image.start_with?('help-me') }
This isn't javascript :D

Comment: @Mark: nicer, yes, but equally useless (here). :)

Comment: `images.all?{ |image| image.start_with?('help-me') }`

Comment: Basically if its not true for all, print an error message. If it is true, continue on.

Comment: Do you want to remove all images that don't start with that string?

Comment: No I just want to exit out altogether.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what you want?

```
if images.find?{ |image| !image.start_with?('help-me') }
  #if you want to exit the app then do
  abort('Dev asked to kill this app because we who knows?')
  #if you want to raise exception then
  raise 'Image found that does not start with help-me'
end
```

Or do you want to `raise` or `puts` ?

```
images.each_with_index do |image, i| 
  unless images[i].start_with?('help-me')
    puts "Image #{image} at index #{i} does not start with 'help-me'"
    #or raise exception here if you want
  end
end
```

Comment: `images.find?`? This is not standard ruby

Answer (score 0):

> Basically if its not true for all, print an error message. If it is true, continue on.

I guess the best option is in the comment above from **@Sergio Tulentsev**.

Anyhow, this is just a further idea:

```
images = ["nginx", "help-me-1", "flip-flop", "help-me-if-you-can", "tick-tack-toe"]

start_with_help_me = images.group_by{ |image| image.start_with?('help-me') }
#=> {false=>["nginx", "flip-flop"], true=>["help-me-1", "help-me-if-you-can"]}

puts "Error" if start_with_help_me[false].any? #=> Error
```

Just in case you would need to get more info, for example:

```
start_with_help_me[false].count #=> 3
start_with_help_me[true].count #=> 2
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `group_by`? Can't you do `puts "Error" if images.any? ...`